# java.lang.NullPointerException Error in Robolectric tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, maven, robolectric

I'm trying to test a method for saving to the internal memory on android but All my tests for it are coming up as "Test in error" when I package the app with Maven, when I check the individual test results it says there was a `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the class, From what I've read it might be something to do with the `context` that I pass in but I've tried several different methods on generating a context and nothing's worked so far, any advice on how to get these to work would be greatly appreciated. The code for the test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SaveSystemTest {

SaveSystem testSS;
Route testRoute;
@Before
public void setup()
{
    testRoute = new Route(new LatLng(54.6279022,-5.9146021), new LatLng(54.6279022,-5.9146021),"testRoute");
    testSS = new SaveSystem("testSave",Robolectric.application.getApplicationContext());
}

@org.junit.Test
public void saveTest()
{
    boolean b = testSS.save(testRoute);
    assertTrue(b);
}
```

The Code for saveSystem.save (Didn't originally have the try catch but I added that trying to get this to work):

```
public boolean save(Route file)
{
    routeList.add(file);
    try
    {
        if(saveToMemory())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("SaveSystem", "Exception: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Code for saveSystem.saveToMemory:

```
private boolean saveToMemory()
{
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(saveFileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(routeList);
        os.close();
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("SaveSystem", "Exception: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include exception stack trace and specify code line where exception is thrown.

Comment: I'm relatively new to android development, how would I get the exception stack trace using maven?

Comment: it depends on your specific situation. If you're using surefire plugin check out `target/surefire-reports` directory for verbose reports on test executions.

Comment: [here's](http://pastebin.com/GAHXLJ8h) the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid mistake, turns out I hadn't initialised the "routeList" List correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use members in your class which are included via Dependency Injection, you should provide a way to pass in a mocked Object for this context, since they are only injected in runtime of your application and not in your tests.

For a good mocking library, have a look at [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).